# Can something be installed in /usr by my app showdown project?

Tags: application-development

I am working on a project for Ubuntu App Showdown Contest (https://launchpad.net/wuuzy) and I wanted to know if it is possible to install things like libraries in /usr. My project, in fact, use an extension system to improve itself with more options. It is like a plugin system and it generates libs which are currently installed in /usr. Also my app generates a gir file installed in /usr/lib/girepository-1.0/ and in /usr/local/share/gir-1.0/. It uses also a gsettings schema which is installed /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/. Naturally I install also the .desktop file in /usr/share/applications even if I have a copy of it in /opt/PROJECT.

So what I really want to know is if this installations targets are allowed for an app which want to join to the Ubuntu App Showdown Contest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for the contest is that your application must entirely run in `/opt`. While in future contests we hope to be able to relax this requirement (as we sandbox Ubuntu better in the future), right now we need to require that your app runs fully in `/opt`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what about the schema? It seems that it must be in /usr

Comment: thus, no lenses? I might be wrong, but seems like Unity lenses should be installed to /usr/share/unity/lenses? Any workarounds for that?

Comment: Lenses installation paths are set up correctly to be run from /opt if you use the Unity Lens Quickly template. Here's an example on how to do it: http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/