# Must apps submitted to the Software Center run from the /opt directory?

Tags: application-development, filesystem, packaging, application-submission

I read this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155714/can-something-be-installed-in-usr-by-my-app-showdown-project), but I'm more confused yet.

- In [developer.ubuntu.com/showdown](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown) I read: "(2) run out of /opt" (**I understand "run out" is not in /opt** **Am I wrong?**)
- In https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines#Packaging I read: "our package should install most files in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/"

It's not clear for me if the app must be in the /opt or out /opt :$

Then, can I use the /usr? Will be the app rejected if it's on /usr?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be confused by the language; they all mean the same, ie:

```
"run out of" == "run in" == "installed in" (all in /opt)
```

[The exceptions are:](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines#Packaging)

- The standard files in `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>` are permitted, such as `copyright`, `changelog`, and `examples`.
- The .desktop file is installed in the standard location `/usr/share/applications`, but must have the prefix `extras-` added to its name. Example: `extras-foobar.desktop` for a package named *foobar*.
- Lenses and scopes are installed in the standard locations, but must have the prefix `extras-` added to their names. Example: `extras-unity-lens-foobar.lens` for a package named *unity-lens-foobar*.

Comment: This is not related to the question but I need to know how to run gsettings from opt.When I submited my application I was told that he application must run from opt.I am not a member of the ubuntu app showdown.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Nevermind asked a separate question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/159673/how-to-use-gsettings-from-opt