# How to use gsettings from /opt

Tags: application-development, gsettings

I have to use gsettings from /opt so that ubuntu maintainers will accept my application.

I may not use /usr or any of the underlying directories so /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try quickly?

```
quickly package --extras
```

This will use the /opt directory.

Comment: I do not use python.

Comment: I use vala and I do not use quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a wrapper script :

GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas /opt/my_app_dir/my_app